# How to write a recipe to install homebrew formulas with Chef 12?

Tags: chef-infra, homebrew, chef-recipe

According to the docs for Chef 12, the default package provider for OS X is homebrew. (assuming it's installed on the target system, which it is)
https://docs.chef.io/resource_package.html

Here's a simple recipe:

```
package 'Install git' do
  package_name 'git'
  homebrew_user 'vagrant'
  action :install
end
```

... and here's what I get:

```
   NoMethodError
   -------------
   undefined method `homebrew_user' for Chef::Resource::MacportsPackage
```

It looks like it's trying to use MacPorts instead. So I try:

```
homebrew_package 'Install git' do
  package_name 'git'
  homebrew_user 'vagrant'
  action :install
end
```

... and I get

```
Error executing action `install` on resource 'homebrew_package[Install git]'

TypeError
---------
no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
```

From the target node if I do:

```
$ /opt/chef/bin/chef-client -v
Chef: 12.2.1
```

...so I know it's using v12. What am I missing here?

Comment: Show stacktrace of TypeError too, please

Comment: stacktrace for TypeError [here](http://pastebin.ca/2968625)

Comment: I had been using the Chef maintained homebrew cookbook, https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/homebrew , to install homebrew itself prior to installing the HB formulas with Chef. I just discovered if I comment out the line (depends  'homebrew', '1.12.0') in my metadata.rb file, I don't get the TypeError and everything works as expected. I don't know enough about Chef to understand how that cookbook is breaking the hombrew_package resource in Chef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your stacktrace of TypeError:

```
/tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/homebrew/libraries/homebrew_package.rb:102:in `getpwnam'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/homebrew/libraries/homebrew_package.rb:102:in `get_response_from_command'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/homebrew/libraries/homebrew_package.rb:70:in `brew'
/tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/homebrew/libraries/homebrew_package.rb:50:in `install_package'
/opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:87:in `block in action_install'
```

If you have the dependency line in your metadata.rb

```
depends 'homebrew'
```

Chef will download the cookbook. This cookbook actually overwrites the Homebrew provider that comes with Chef12. And looks like it is just a bug in the cookbook.

However, README of the cookbook says, that it is not necessary for Chef12+:

> This cookbook includes a package resource provider to use homebrew.
>   Under Chef 12+, this is not necessary, and the code doesn't actually
>   get used on Chef 12+. This was preserved to maintain backwards
>   compatiblity with older versions of Chef

So as you figured it out. You don't have to (and better shouldn't) add dependency to this cookbook.
Removing the `depends 'homebrew'` line from metadata.rb makes Chef use the built-in Homebrew provider, which works.

Comment: When I read the homebrew cookbook's README I had thought, "...the code doesn't actually get used on Chef 12+", meant that I would be ok as long as I didn't include any recipe's that made use of that provider. I didn't understand that the dependency on that cookbook would load everything.

Comment: Yes, that sentence is actually misleading. Libraries, along with resources and providers are always loaded, even if no recipe from cookbook is run at all.

Comment: I removed the dependency on homebrew cookbook and just wrote a homebrew installer myself. Still scratching my head as to why Chef is not picking the homebrew_package provider as it's default for the mac_os_x platform per the docs.